# Apache Kafka partition offset rewinds during rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

We have a Kafka consumer application implemented using SpringBoot and Apache camel with manual commit. Topic which we consume has 30 partitions and retention period of 7 days. Consumer application deployed in 2 instances for HA and parallel processing is implemented using Apache Camel concurrent consumer configuration. Once we consume the data, we do message transformation and send to a REST endpoint. We have implemented the Circuit breaker pattern(Apache Camel Throttling route policy ) and for any runtime time issue with REST, Circuit Breaker kicks in and stops message consumption from Kafka Topic. Also we have are using the
`max.poll.records = 100` and `heartbeat interval = 1 ms` 
instead of default values to address the frequent commit offset failure exceptions. Load on the `topic = 200 tps`.

Problem statement:

Last week, we saw an issue - REST endpoint was slow in processing,  and we saw the consumer group rebalance activity in broker logs and during this rebalance one of the partition consumer rewind the offset to 5 days old  offset(almost 1 million back, offset id) and started the reprocessing of the messages causing huge duplication.
I looked in to both consumer log and broker log and not seen any exception or error and we are using the offset strategy as Latest.  Also as I mentioned above we are using the manual commit and I believe,  since consumer commits the offsets for every batch,

**I expect when rebalance happens it should have rewind to at most one batch old offset, not 5 days old offset.**

We have this implementation more than a year and saw this issue first time.  We are using default values for most of the broker and consumer configuration other than max.poll.records, heartbeat interval and session timeout.

`Kafka Broker = 2.4`
`Apache Camel= 3.0`

Comment: Did you figure out the cause by any chance? I'm noticing similar behavior on my kafka cluster.